# HTML5 Canvas element not appear in compiled Android Ionic but works in browser 'Ionic Serve'

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, html5-canvas, ionic4

I used face-api.js in my Ionic 4 project to detect face from camera stream. however the detection canvas only works in browser `ionic serve` and not working after i compiled it into Android apk. I can see all my models loaded in Android debug console but none of the `<canvas>` appended into my html. where did i do wrong?

**page.html**

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col class="ion-text-center" size="12">
    <div #videoContainer></div>
    <div>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    </div>
<ion-col>
```

**page.ts**

```
  videoLoad() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('video')
      .addEventListener('play', async () => {

        const labeledFaceDescriptors = await this.loadLabeledImages()
        const faceMatcher = new faceapi.FaceMatcher(labeledFaceDescriptors, 0.6)

        const displaySize = { width: this.video.width, height: this.video.height }

        const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas')


        faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)

        await faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('https://www.test.com/models');
        await faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('https://www.test.com/models');
        await faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('https://www.test.com/models');
        await faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('https://www.test.com/models');
        await faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri('https://www.test.com/models');

        setInterval(async () => {

          const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(this.video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptors().withFaceExpressions()
          const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)

          const results = resizedDetections.map(d => faceMatcher.findBestMatch(d.descriptor))

          const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext("2d")

          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
          results.forEach((result, i) => {
            const box = resizedDetections[i].detection.box
            const drawBox = new faceapi.draw.DrawBox(box, { label: result.toString() })
            if (result.label == 'unknown') {

            } else {
              console.log(result.label);
            }
            drawBox.draw(canvas)
          })
        }, 800)
      })
  }
```